# Linux kernel's symbol has two addresses?

Tags: linux, kernel, symbols

Found out kernel symbol has 2 address when debuging some problem of coredump process.

```bash
    (gdb) info line binfmt_elf.c:2385
    Line 2385 of "fs/binfmt_elf.c" starts at address 0xffff00000830dd84 <elf_core_dump+3460> and ends at 0xffff00000830dd88 <elf_core_dump+3464>.
    Line 2385 of "fs/binfmt_elf.c" starts at address 0xffff00000831083c <elf_core_dump+3460> and ends at 0xffff000008310840 <elf_core_dump+3464>.
    (gdb) info line binfmt_elf.c:2345
    Line 2345 of "fs/binfmt_elf.c" starts at address 0xffff0000083106b8 <elf_core_dump+3072> and ends at 0xffff0000083106c0 <elf_core_dump+3080>.
    Line 2345 of "fs/binfmt_elf.c" starts at address 0xffff00000830dbfc <elf_core_dump+3068> and ends at 0xffff00000830dc04 <elf_core_dump+3076>.
```

nm tell the same result:

```bash
    nm vmlinux | grep elf_core_dump
    ffff00000830d000 t elf_core_dump
    ffff00000830fab8 t elf_core_dump
```

plat infomation:aarch64,kernel(4.20) was build by my self,config was copied from alpine virt aarch64

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `elf_core_dump` is a **static** one, so it can be defined in the several source files.

As for funny output of gdb, in which the line

```
Line 2385 of "fs/binfmt_elf.c"
```

appears twice, then it is because the source file `fs/binfmt_elf.c` is **included into other source file**, `fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c` by using

```
/*
 * We share all the actual code with the native (64-bit) version.
 */
#include "binfmt_elf.c"
```

(https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/fs/compat_binfmt_elf.c#L131).

So every function in the `binfmt_elf.c` is actually defined twice in the resulted kernel image:

- the first definition is created when compile the file `binfmt_elf.c`
- the second definition is created when compile the file `compat_binfmt_elf.c`.